# Is it possible to get a "reverse video" effect for selected text when using iTerm2 (like gnome-terminal)?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal, iterm2

I've been developing in linux at my day job for the past year or so and while I'm quite happy to be back in OS X I'm missing some features from Ubuntu/Gnome.

Is it possible to get the reverse video effect when selection text in gnome-terminal in iTerm2?

**EDIT:**

Sounds like this is an unimplemented feature. To see the feature request (with screenshots of the desired effect!), check [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2475&thanks=2475&ts=1369772432) out.

Comment: For those of us OS X users who don't have GNOME Terminal, can you explain what the "reverse video" effect is?

Comment: @slhck unless I'm mistaken, they are referring to a standard unix color option, to flip the foreground and background colors

Comment: @demure Could be. Reading "reverse video" I was thinking about moving video of some kind.

Comment: @slhck: just added a link to my feature request which has screen shots. :)

Answer (score 0):

For iTerm2, go to Preferences -> Profiles -> Your Profile -> Color, then set "Selection" to match "Foreground", and "Selected Text" to match "Background".
Currently open windows will not reflect change.

**Note:** This approximates, but is not true, reverse video.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This isn't really very close to what I'm hoping for. The reason this comes up for me is that I have something like `ag` or `grep` that colorizes it's output. When I read through code in the terminal, it's really helpful to be able to make quick selections with the mouse to add in visual anchor points for what I'm currently reading/already read. But in iTerm2, the selection is always a flat color, without preserving the colors beneath the selection. That's why I want the reverse video effect.

Comment: @TimVisher you might have to submit a feature request.